# Surjective morphism of complete non-singular curves is normalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

My syllabus on algebraic geometry states the following:

''Let $\phi: X \to Y$ be a surjective morphism of complete non-singular curves. Then $X$ is the normalization of $Y$ in the function field of $X$. In particular, the morphism $\phi$ is finite. ''

How do we know that $X$ is the normalization of $Y$?

The definition of normalization we use is the following:

''A normalization of $Y$ in $k(X)$ is a finite surjective morphism $\pi: X \to Y$ such that $X$ is normal and the extension of function fields corresponding to $\pi$ is the extension $k(Y) \supset k(X)$. ''

I understand that $\phi$ is surjective and $X$ is normal (ie. $\mathcal{O}_{X, P}$ is integrally closed $\forall P \in X$) because it is non-singular, but how do we know that the extension of function fields is exactly $k(Y) \supset k(X)$ and that $\phi$ is a finite morphism?

Comment: This statement is correct but needs a proof.

Comment: I think I see why $\phi $ is finite: $\phi $ is proper because $ X $ is complete, and quasi-finite because $ X$ has the co-finite topology, so $\phi^{-1}(P) $ is finite. Hence $\phi $ is finite. Is this enough? I suppose I was confused because the syllabus seems to have the implications reversed.

Comment: Your proof is correct.